# GMAPS for Rails - how to handle blank addresses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using gem 'gmaps4rails'.  It works fine as long as the Location record has address information.  If the address is blank, Rails won't update the record.  How can I test for blank and bypass the GMAPS?

This is the models/location.rb:

```
 acts_as_gmappable :check_process => false

 def gmaps4rails_address
   "#{address1}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zipcode}"
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should skip validation and code yours. [Doc is here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization).

```
acts_as_gmappable :validation => false
```